# indices of elements which satisfy a given condition

Tags: c#, linq, list

i am looking for a linq expression which is extension of [FindIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1xzf2ca%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method. It returns only first index. I want all indices in a list which satisfy a condition.

for example:

```
var indx = myList.FindIndex(x => (x <= -Math.PI / 3) || (x >= Math.PI / 3));
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Then you need to use LINQ since `List.FindIndex` returns just the first. You can use the overload of `Enumerable.Select` that gives the index of an item in a sequence to create an anonymous type.

```
IEnumerable<int> allIndices = myList
    .Select((item, index) => new { item, index })
    .Where(x => (x.item <= -Math.PI / 3) || (x.item >= Math.PI / 3))
    .Select(x => x.index);
```

Comment: There's also an overload of `Where()` that gives you the index, so you can omit the first `Select()`.

Comment: svick -- once you've applied the overload of Where(), does that not change the indices?

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this

```
IList(int) indx = myList.Select((x, i) => (x <= -Math.PI / 3) || (x >= Math.PI / 3) ? i : -1).Where(i => i != -1).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

I would start by projecting your list into a set of tuples:

```
var indices = myList.Select((x, i) => new { Value = x, Index = i })
    .Where(o => (o.Value <= -Math.PI / 3) || (o.Value >= Math.PI / 3))
    .Select(o => o.Index);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Select` => `Where` => `Select` solution is the cleanest approach.

If you want something more creative and compact:

```
bool Condition(double item)
{
    return (item <= -Math.PI / 3) || (item >= Math.PI / 3);
}

var indices = myList.SelectMany((x, i) =>
                         Enumerable.Repeat(i, Condition(x) ? 1 : 0)).ToList();
```

The inner `Enumerable.Repeat` will produce the index when the `Condition` is met otherwise it will return nothing. The `SelectMany` will flatten the collection of collections to produce the indices.

This can be generalized:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<int> FindIndices<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> collection,
        Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        return collection.SelectMany((x, i) =>
                    Enumerable.Repeat(i, predicate(x) ? 1 : 0));
    }
}

var indices = myList.FindIndices(item =>
                   (item <= -Math.PI / 3) || (item >= Math.PI / 3));
```

Comment: I seem to remember that if you project a collection using a function that can generate null values, they will automatically be filtered from the result set.  So I think you can do `myList.Select((x, i) => Condition(i) ? new int?(i) : default(int?)).Select(i => i.GetValueOrDefault())`.  Not sure if that will work though.

Comment: `Select` does not perform any filtering and `i.GetValueOrDefault()` will return `0` for any `null` integers.

Answer (score 1):

This is another way of getting the result you need:

```
IEnumerable<int> result = Enumerable.Range(0, myList.Count).Where(i => (myList[i] <= -Math.PI / 3) || (myList[i] >= Math.PI / 3));
```

Comment: i like the idea.. nice

Answer (score 0):

I think it will works for you:

```
var indx = myList.Where(x => (x <= -Math.PI / 3) || (x >= Math.PI / 3))
                 .Select((element, index) => index)
                 .ToList();
```

Comment: This is wrong as the index in the Select() is the new index after filtering with the Where() so all you get is {0, 1, 2, ...}.